# How to create a 2D tile-map in python ASCII style

Tags: tilemap, python, rpg

Still learning about python programming and I wanted to create a little map like below but the thing is I know a for loop will draw down not draw across. However, I want to change the size of the area and add new tiles later on. I understand that this might be a really bad question but I cannot wrap my head around this.

```
posX = 0
posY = 0

tile1 = 'X'
tile2 = 'O'

width = int(12)
height = int(9)

'''

<--- 12 --->
XXXXXXXXXXXX ^
XOOOOOOOOOOX |
XOOOOOOOOOOX |
XOOOOOOOOOOX 
XOOOOOOOOOOX 9
XOOOOOOOOOOX 
XOOOOOOOOOOX |
XOOOOOOOOOOX |
XXXXXXXXXXXX v

'''


#Draws down and across
for i in range(width):
    print(tile1 * width)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what specific aspect you're having trouble with here. What do you mean by "a for loop will draw down not draw across"? A for loop will do whatever you program it to do. Would you like to show us the for loop code you've tried for this so far, and explain how its behaviour differs from what you want?

Comment: To expand the map horizontally, isn't it just a matter of printing longer lines of text?

Comment: I am trying to create a row and column for each tile. I made it so the top left would be 0, 0 and the bottom right would be 12, 9 this way I can put inside of each row and column a type of tile I want for the area/map I made. Using a for loop for it (I'll update it won't work)

Answer (score 1):

You can split it on three elements and only one need `for`-loop

1. Top line `XXXXXXXXXXXX`

   ```python
   print(tile1 * width)
   ```
2. Middle lines `XOOOOOOOOOOX`

   There will be `height-2` lines and they will have `"X"`, next `"O" * (width-2)`, next `"X"`

   ```python
   for i in range(height-2):
       print(tile1 + (tile2 * (width-2)) + tile1)
   ```
3. Bottom line `XXXXXXXXXXXX`

   ```python
   print(tile1 * width)
   ```

Code:

```python
posX = 0
posY = 0

tile1 = 'X'
tile2 = 'O'

width = 12   # no need `int()`
height = 9   # no need `int()`

# top line

print(tile1 * width)

# middle lines

for i in range(height-2):
    print(tile1 + (tile2 * (width-2)) + tile1)

# bottom line

print(tile1 * width)
```

---

**EDIT:**

To make it useful put all lines on list - i.e `all_lines` - using `append()` instead of `print()`. But keep every line as list of chars instead of string with all chars (I will use `[ ]` in code to do it).

It means

```
['X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X']
```

instead of

```
XOOOOOOOOOOX
```

And then you can easily replace elements

```python
all_lines[1][1] = '@'
```

where you have positions `[Y][X]` not `[X][Y]` - `all_lines[Y][X]` or in other words `all_lines[row][col]`

```python
posX = 0
posY = 0

tile1 = 'X'
tile2 = 'O'

width = 12   # no need `int()`
height = 9   # no need `int()`

all_lines = []

# top line

all_lines.append([tile1] * width)

# middle lines
for i in range(height-2):
    all_lines.append([tile1] + ([tile2] * (width-2)) + [tile1])

# bottom line

all_lines.append([tile1] * width)

print(all_lines)
```

and this gives 2D list

```
[
  ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'], 
  ['X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X'], 
  ['X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X'], 
  ['X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X'], 
  ['X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X'], 
  ['X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X'], 
  ['X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X'], 
  ['X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'X'], 
  ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
]
```

and you can display it using `for`-loop and `"".join()`

```python
for line in all_lines:
    print("".join(line))  # <-- join list of chars to one string and display it
```

Result with `@`

```
XXXXXXXXXXXX
X@OOOOOOOOOX
XOOOOOOOOOOX
XOOOOOOOOOOX
XOOOOOOOOOOX
XOOOOOOOOOOX
XOOOOOOOOOOX
XOOOOOOOOOOX
XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

---

**EDIT:**

To work with map you can also use other `for`-loop

```python
for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        print(all_lines[y][x], end='')  # draw without going to new line
    print()  # go to new line
```

and then you can use it with extra `if/else` to test or change elements

```python
for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        if all_lines[y][x] == '@':
           all_lines[y][x] = '%'
        #print(all_lines[y][x], end='')
    #print()
```

You can also use more Pythonic method with enumerate

```python
for y, line in enumerate(all_lines):
    for x, item in enumerate(line):
        if item == '@':
           all_lines[y][x] = '%'  # it has to replace in original `all_lines`
        #print(item, end='')
    #print()
```